# Can I draw on a Form, above all controls?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics, draw

Is it possible for me to draw ABOVE all controls on a `form`?
I have some controls (`textboxes`, `buttons`, `COM objects`) on my `form,` and I wish to draw ON them, overriding any pixels previously drawn by them.
I am using `Windows Forms` on `C#`.
NOTE: the `Graphics` class draws under the controls...

Comment: Can you show in code how you are currently trying to draw on the main form?

Comment: I know it's a WinForms question, but I can't resist mentioning that WPF has this built in with Adorner Layers.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm way too late in the game, and there is nothing wrong with the accepted answer, but I found it too complicated and somehow hard to understand, so I come up with a "hack" for it.

**1. Make a custom `Panel` with the following code.**

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Create a `TransparentPanel` exactly the same size as the `Form`, over every control currently on the `Form`, bring it to the front, and set its `BackColor` to `Transparent`, `Enable` to `false`.**

**3. Now everything you draw within `OnPaint` will be drawn "above" any controls, and it will not "block" any interactable controls such as `TextBox`.**